# WSAEFAULT error using recvfrom() in c++ for Windows

Tags: c++, udp, codeblocks, winsock2

I'm writing a UDP server as part of an application. In the following snippet:

```
int ServerManager::onListen(void * data)
{
    int numbytes;
    char buf[512];
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(sockaddr_in);
    struct sockaddr_in addr;
    if((numbytes = recvfrom(listenSocket,buf, sizeof(buf),0,(SOCKADDR*) &addr, &addrlen)
    == -1))
    {
        std::cout << "recv error:" << WSAGetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "done";
    return 0;
}
```

I am receiving error code 10014 "WSAEFAULT", and never reaching "done". I using c++ and winsock2. If I replace the last two parameters with NULL the recvfrom() call works fine. From what I've seen of this problem elsewhere, I expected setting the addrlen and buffer up properly to solve the issue, but with the code as simple as it now is, I'm struggling to find the reason that it is failing. I feel like it must be something simple I've overlooked and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is that you actual code?

Comment: It is. The binding of listenSocket etc is in a separate class function. If that's relevant, I can post it (but it's fairly long and runs fine).

Comment: WSAEFAULT occurs because buf is invalid or too small, or because fromLen is too small. Since from is optional, try it without from and see if you still get the error.

Comment: I replaced both addrlen and addr seperately with NULL. In both cases, I received the same error. If both are replaced with NULL, the code runs without complaint - but I will need the address later so that isn't sufficient.

Comment: It's not an ipv6 packet is it? Have you tried making addr a SOCKADDR and `addrLen = sizeof(addr);`?

Comment: I tested that and received the same error.

Comment: Ah! fixed it. The socket was set to AF_UNSPEC rather than AF_INET. Changing that solved the problem.

Comment: @kfsone: `SOCKADDR` is the same as `sockaddr_in` for historic reasons.  You probably meant `SOCKADDR_STORAGE` instead, which reserves enough space to hold any IPv4 or IPv6 address.

Answer (score 2):

The error was caused by the settings of the socket.
Changing the ai_family from "AF_UNSPEC" to "AF_INET" resolved the issue in this case, but to retain ipv6 compatibility, the code is modified as follows.

```
int ServerManager::onListen(void * data)
{
    int numbytes;
    char buf[MAXBUFLEN];
    SOCKADDR_STORAGE addr;
    socklen_t addrlen = sizeof(addr);
    if((numbytes = recvfrom(listenSocket,buf, sizeof(buf),0,(LPSOCKADDR) &addr, &addrlen)
    == -1))
    {
        std::cout << "recv error:" << WSAGetLastError();
        return -1;
    }
    std::cout << "done";
    return 0;
}
```